# Extract elements from bs4.element.ResultSet

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm looking to extract the two numeric value from this bs4.

```
forecast = [<div class="cell "><span>1.2</span><span class="m-unit"></span> - <span>2.0</span><span class="m-unit"></span></div>,
 <div class="cell "><span>1.5</span><span class="m-unit"></span> - <span>2.6</span><span class="m-unit"></span></div>,
```

Do you know how to integrate them directly into a dataframe?

```
forecast[1].contents[3]
```

But is not robust to extract all the numerical values from the forecast bs4 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pattern is always identical and no other deviations occur, the following procedure can be followed:

```
pd.DataFrame([e.text.split('-') for e in forcast])
```

**Note:** *For reliable results, more detailed information is needed in the questionnaire.*

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

html = '''<div class="cell "><span>1.2</span><span class="m-unit"></span> - <span>2.0</span><span class="m-unit"></span></div>
<div class="cell "><span>1.5</span><span class="m-unit"></span> - <span>2.6</span><span class="m-unit"></span></div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

forcast = soup.select('div')

pd.DataFrame([e.text.split('-') for e in forcast])
```

##### Output

|  | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.2 | 2 |
| 1 | 1.5 | 2.6 |